# Python script not working on crontab

Tags: python, cron

I have this python script. I'm trying to run it on a crontab, but it isn't working:

```
from datetime import datetime
x="Hello, it is now %s." % datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
import csv
try:
    with open('output.csv', 'w+') as csvFile:
        writer=csv.writer(csvFile)
        writer.writerow(x)
finally:
    csvFile.close()
```

The crontab is defined as:

```
attyan22@LAPTOP-SGBTV53C:~$ crontab -l
* * * * * python hello_time.py
```

```
attyan22@LAPTOP-SGBTV53C:~$ service crond start
crond: unrecognized service
```

I want to run automatically, but it does not working. This is just test .

Comment: 1) Is cron active? 2) Does your script work in a terminal? 3) Does cron find python and the file hello_time.py?

Comment: 1 crond not  2yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give full path to `hello_time.py`.

Try

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/hello_time.py
```

Replace `/path/to` with actual path for `hello_time.py`. This you can get by running `pwd` from the directory it's located in.

Comment: like this * * * * * /usr/bin/python C:\Users\a.sakata\Desktop\python_lesson\hello_time.py ? but still no

Comment: C:\ ? It is a windows or Linux environment?

Comment: Are you using WSL?

Comment: I use windows ubuntu

Comment: Then try `/mnt/c/Users\a.sakata\Desktop\python_lesson\hello_time.py` as path. But I would advise reading up a bit on Linux in addition, if you want to use it to learn programming.

Comment: * * * * * /usr/bin/python /mnt/c/Users\a.sakata\Desktop\python_lesson\hello_time.py                          or        * * * * * /usr/bin/env python /mnt/c/Users\a.sakata\Desktop\python_lesson\hello_time.py   but no.          python file works in prompt only ubuntu is problem.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. You need to use forward slashes in the path, not backslashes. Anyway, my advice stands.

Comment: backslash to forwardslash does not works. also check on / off by using chkconfig or sys-rc-conf  ,But I can not install both.   thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92606/discussion-between-vidarlo-and-atsushi-sakata).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but figured I would put it out there. ran into the same problem but found the solution on my own after finding the replies unhelpful here. It seems like you had problems with crontab not working on WSL. crontab is installed but it isn't running.

use `service --status-all` to check all possible services (you might want/need `sudo` at the beginning). the crontab service could be listed as "cron", "crond", "crontab"... find the name listed on your machine and use that to check status, start or stop the service.
`service cron status`, `service cron start` and `service cron stop`

Comment: It has been over 6 years since Ubuntu switched to `systemd`, and thus the command is no longer `service cron start` but `systemctl start cron`. Yes, they are available for backwards compatibility, but the command you're really using is `systemctl`.